# Accessing ancestors of array with given value

Tags: jq

I can't seem to find the secret sauce to make jq do what I want.

Given the following contrived input:

```
{
    "node1": {
        "1": {
            "Aliases": ["one", "uno"]
        },
        "2": {
            "Aliases": ["two", "dos"]
        }
    },
    "node2": {
        "a": {
            "Aliases": ["alpha"]
        },
        "b": {
            "Aliases": ["bravo"]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return the keys of the ancestors of `Aliases` when `Aliases` contains a particular value.

For example, given the search key `dos`, I want to return `node1` and `2`.

You can play with this data [in jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/gatqyHXh4I).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(paths | select(.[-2] == "Aliases")) as $p
| select( "dos" == getpath($p))
| $p[:-2][]
```

Notice that there's no need for an additional variable (`. as $in`).